# Voltage tester indicates the wall has an electical charge

Tags: electrical, voltage

My Dad installed a bar on the wall, and put his voltage tester to the bar, and it lit up red.

Then he tested the wall ( *with the voltage tester* ), and a couple of adjacent walls - 2 red, one not.

He removed the bar ( *and the screws* ) opened the wall where he had installed the screws, and didn't find a wire ... chances are it was a previous short ?

Any suggestions, short of removing the sheetrock around the room and to find the problem?

Comment: what do you mean by a "bar"? What are you trying to do? What is your problem? Your description, at least to me, is very vague.

Comment: Can you be specific about the voltage tester? The little stick ones that beep are notorious for falsing.

Comment: Does this tester have a battery?

Comment: What make and model of voltage tester are you using?

Comment: A volt meter is a tester, I can plug my top of the line Fluke meters in any receptacle in the US and put the other end in any bodily orifice of yours you choose and guess what . Even standing on your head 1 foot or 2 you will measure a voltage so you would be the same potential as your wall, so what is your question, you ask for suggestions, take an electronics class.

Answer (score 1):

If the "voltage tester" is one of those "tick tracer" type that don't actually need to touch two wires (or one wire and ground), they function my simply detecting magnetic fields AROUND wires. So they will "light up" by just being NEAR wires, even wires BEHIND something else. Basically, it doesn't mean anything in the scenario you described.

Comment: Nit picking, but non-contact testers detect electric fields by measuring capacitave coupling. You can't have magnetic fields with no current, and NCV work on open circuits.